# How can I fix this CORS with Socket.io?

Tags: html, node.js, web, socket.io, cors

I'm having trouble migrating my locally hosted chat application using Socket.io to my live cloud server. I am aware there are solutions out there, however, I cannot find anything that solves my problem.

I am receiving **"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at.... (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)"** 
'''

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000)

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('new-user', name => {
        users[socket.id] = name
        socket.broadcast.emit('user-connected', name)
    })
    socket.on('send-chat-message', message => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message', {message: message, name: 
            users[socket.id]})
    })
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', users[socket.id])
       delete users[socket.id]

    })  

})
```

Above is the server.js file.

```
    const socket = io('<url>:3000')
    const messageForm = document.getElementById('send-container')
    const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input')
    const messageContainer = document.getElementById('message-container')
```

This is the script my app is using, the  is replaced by mine, it just masked on here.

**Things I have tried:**

- Setting headers using "Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in my Apache & Nginx config
- Changing the url on the script
- Changing the ports

So far I've no luck, please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
// Allow all origins
io.origins('*');
```

[source](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server-origins-value)